# как создать проект в laravel определённой версии (напрмер 7) через команду new

Tags: php, laravel, composer

изучаю laravel скачал установщик (installer) и хочу создать проект с помощью команды laravel new name-project однако инсталлер ругается просит php 7.3 так как создаёт по умолчанию проект на 8й версии а у меня php версии 7.2 на опенсервере. менять версию пхп не хочу не подскажите как задать версию laravel для проекта?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вот так с помощью `composer`
`composer create-project laravel/laravel=7.0 PROJECT_NAME --prefer-dist` 
[ссылочка на laravel.com](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2)

Comment: да так можно но это не через установщик а напрямую через композер скачиваем проект с предустановленными программами, а я хочу посмотреть что входит в проект если создать проект через команду new установщика

Comment: @ahel73 а. так вам надо было так и задать вопрос про разницу. разница настолько небольшая, что ее почти нет. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31889067/laravel-framework-difference-between-creating-a-new-project-via-laravel-or-com такой вопрос задавался. и вот еще https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26424

Comment: спасибо!) я тогда изучу ваши ссылки